# How do I get a new line in a textbox in my code?

Tags: vb.net

So I am trying to grab input from a textbox and put it in a seperate textbox. I need 7 days worth of text box. I have no problem actually grabbing the input from the textbox  but I can't get it in to a seperate box. (if that makes sense)

I've tried using all the vbCrLf, vbcr or whatever all those but it still will not go on to a seperate line.

```
Dim Number As String = Me.InputTextbox.Text
        Me.UnitsListView.Items.Add(Number & vbCr)

    'Make the textbox delete the text once the button is clicked
    InputTextbox.Text = String.Empty
```

i am expecting it to go in a line like

```
111
222
333
444
```

but instead its going like

```
22232 334 333 4555
4444 5555 555 66
```

Comment: Did you set the Multiline property of the TextBox to True?

Comment: Yes I did but its still  not letting me add multiple lines of data, its just accepting one number

Comment: I do have it already formatted to look like code it just didnt show up properly when i posted the question its still not working

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only place you're even attempting to add a line break there is the text in a new `ListViewItem` so why exactly would you expect that to affect a `TextBox`?  The code you have makes no sense in light of the explanation of your problem.  If you want a line break in a `TextBox` then it should be obvious that you need a line break in the `String` assign to the `Text` of that `TextBox` but nowhere in your code is there any chance of that happening.  Given that the proper way to specify a line break is `Environment.NewLine` and the proper way to append text to the contents of a `TextBox` is to call its `AppendText` method, the code to append a new line of text to the contents of a `TextBox` should look something like this:

```
myTextBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & newText)
```

Even if you don't want to use those "proper" options, you still need to actually change the `Text` of the `TextBox` if you expect the `TextBox` contents to change:

```
myTextBox.Text &= ControlChars.CrLf & newText
```

or:

```
myTextBox.Text = myTextBox.Text & ControlChars.CrLf & newText
```

Comment: sorry the list i was wanting was in the listview box all i need was for it to be a list going down whether it was a textbox or a listview I am new to this programming stuff and I'm not understanding it very well

Comment: I just tried that and it worked!! oh my god thank you so much I have been trying to figure that out all day!!